# Cant load D-Link DWA-131 version E1 on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, 15.04, realtek

The device is seen as:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2001:3319 D-Link Corp.
```

I followed the instructions from here: http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/in/2013-11-16-d-link-dwa-131-n300-usb-wifi-adapter (for Version E1) and got the module 8192eu.ko compiled as needed.

However, when I load the module with insmod it just responds "Killed" and dmesg shows following:

```
[  837.829178] RTL871X: module init start
[  837.829180] RTL871X: rtl8192eu v4.3.1.1_11320.20140505
[  837.829187] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000050
[  837.829189] IP: [<ffffffffc124078d>] rtw_ndev_notifier_call+0xc/0x65 [8192eu]
[  837.829200] PGD 0 
[  837.829201] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 
[  837.829202] Modules linked in: 8192eu(OE+) pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) cfg80211 binfmt_misc joydev hid_generic usbhid uas usb_storage fglrx(POE) mxm_wmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_hda_controller snd_hda_codec kvm snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_soc_rt5640 snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_core serio_raw snd_compress snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_pcm mei_me amd_iommu_v2 lpc_ich mei shpchp snd_rawmidi snd_seq 8250_fintek snd_seq_device tpm_infineon snd_timer dw_dmac wmi dw_dmac_core snd_soc_sst_acpi video 8250_dw snd i2c_hid
[  837.829220]  hid soundcore i2c_designware_platform acpi_pad spi_pxa2xx_platform i2c_designware_core intel_smartconnect mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 psmouse ahci alx libahci mdio sdhci_acpi sdhci
[  837.829226] CPU: 5 PID: 5478 Comm: insmod Tainted: P           OE  3.19.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu
[  837.829227] Hardware name: MSI MS-7917/Z97 GAMING 5 (MS-7917), BIOS V1.0 04/08/2014
[  837.829228] task: ffff8803f5e8a740 ti: ffff8800b86d8000 task.ti: ffff8800b86d8000
[  837.829228] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffc124078d>]  [<ffffffffc124078d>] rtw_ndev_notifier_call+0xc/0x65 [8192eu]
[  837.829238] RSP: 0018:ffff8800b86dbc90  EFLAGS: 00010206
[  837.829239] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffffffc12af080 RCX: 0000000000000009
[  837.829240] RDX: ffff8800b86dbcb0 RSI: 0000000000000005 RDI: ffffffffc12af080
[  837.829240] RBP: ffff8800b86dbce8 R08: 00000000000177c0 R09: ffffffff813b755d
[  837.829241] R10: ffff88041ed577c0 R11: ffffea000fd78000 R12: ffff88040be22000
[  837.829241] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffffffff81ce54d8 R15: ffffffff81ce5400
[  837.829242] FS:  00007f1be757b700(0000) GS:ffff88041ed40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  837.829243] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  837.829244] CR2: 0000000000000050 CR3: 00000000ba493000 CR4: 00000000001407e0
[  837.829244] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[  837.829245] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[  837.829245] Stack:
[  837.829246]  ffffffff816babb2 ffffffffc0415000 ffff880000000000 ffff8800b86dbce8
[  837.829247]  ffff88040be22000 ffff8800b86dbce8 ffffffff81c1a080 ffff8803f0fd2800
[  837.829248]  0000000000000000 ffffffffc0415000 ffff8800b86dbef8 ffff8800b86dbcf8
[  837.829249] Call Trace:
[  837.829253]  [<ffffffff816babb2>] ? register_netdevice_notifier+0x92/0x1d0
[  837.829254]  [<ffffffffc0415000>] ? 0xffffffffc0415000
[  837.829256]  [<ffffffffc0415000>] ? 0xffffffffc0415000
[  837.829266]  [<ffffffffc1240b46>] rtw_ndev_notifier_register+0x15/0x17 [8192eu]
[  837.829271]  [<ffffffffc041506a>] rtw_drv_entry+0x6a/0x1000 [8192eu]
[  837.829273]  [<ffffffff81002148>] do_one_initcall+0xd8/0x210
[  837.829276]  [<ffffffff811d7529>] ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x189/0x200
[  837.829278]  [<ffffffff810fae88>] ? load_module+0x15b8/0x1d00
[  837.829280]  [<ffffffff810faec2>] load_module+0x15f2/0x1d00
[  837.829281]  [<ffffffff810f6680>] ? store_uevent+0x40/0x40
[  837.829283]  [<ffffffff810fb746>] SyS_finit_module+0x86/0xb0
[  837.829285]  [<ffffffff817cb70d>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[  837.829285] Code: 02 48 81 c7 e8 3a 00 00 ba 06 00 00 00 e8 27 f4 ff ff b8 00 00 00 00 5d c3 b8 00 00 00 00 c3 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 8b 82 e8 01 00 00 <48> 81 78 50 ee 1a 25 c1 75 49 55 48 89 e5 41 54 53 48 89 d3 49 
[  837.829297] RIP  [<ffffffffc124078d>] rtw_ndev_notifier_call+0xc/0x65 [8192eu]
[  837.829306]  RSP <ffff8800b86dbc90>
[  837.829307] CR2: 0000000000000050
[  837.829308] ---[ end trace 96b1b59d12928441 ]---
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!